# VX Connectbot connects to bionic sshd but not to focal sshd, why and what can i do?

Tags: android, sshd

Seems there's been a subtle shift in sshd such that now VX Connectbot no longer gets any response.  is it a bug?  a new feature?

VX Connectbot (1.7.1-29 on android 6.0.1 G900PVPS3CQD1) can connect to the bionic sshd just fine, even if it's running on the focal kernel, but gets no response from the focal sshd.  What's up with that?

/etc/ssh/sshd_config is identical on bionic and focal.  ufw isn't installed on either of them.  Either can be reached from other ubuntu installs.  it's just VX Connectbot that's getting the snub.

i tried to use the bionic sshd as a workaround.  if substituted directly into focal it won't start.  it'll run and receive connections in a bionic chroot, but from there i can't reach the focal x11vnc thru the usual tunnel.

Anything else i should try?

Will i have to find a new ssh client for android?  is there a shortcut to trying a slew of them, is there a good place to see good recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be more secure focal sshd by default refrains from offering as many key options, see workaround here:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/1877496